# HP ProBook Laptop paring with logitech wireless mice mulfunction

Tags: wireless-networking, mouse

I have two logitech wireless mice (one is a laser device and the other uses radio frequency - I am not a tech expert) that used to work on my Hp ProBook computer but after upgrading the logitech software, one failed to connect. I believe that can be resolved by uninstalling the upgraded software. But now my second mouse ceased to connect and the pop up message I receive say windows failed to recognise the device and has stopped the service.

My question is ... how can I get windows to re-start the service again? If this has to do with the devices - the wireless receiver, how can I re-activate it?